# Convert "Q12019" object to datetime64

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe, where one column contains a string for the quarter and year in the following format: Q12019

My Question: ​How do I convert this into datetime format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pandas [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html#pandas-periodindex) to accomplish this. Just reformat your quarters column to the expected format `%Y-%q` (with some help from [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), move the year to the front):

```
reformatted_quarters = df['QuarterYear'].str.replace(r'(Q\d)(\d+)', r'\2\1')
print(reformatted_quarters)
```

This prints:

```
0    2019Q1
1    2018Q2
2    2019Q4
Name: QuarterYear, dtype: object
```

Then, feed this result to `PeriodIndex` to get the `datetime` format. Use `'Q'` to specify a quarterly frequency:

```
datetimes = pd.PeriodIndex(reformatted_quarters, freq='Q').to_timestamp()
print(datetimes)
```

This prints:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01', '2018-04-01', '2019-10-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Quarter', freq=None)
```

---

**Note**: Pandas `PeriodIndex` functionality experienced a regression in behavior (documented [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26109)), so for Pandas versions greater than 0.23.4, you'll need to use `reformatted_quarters.values` instead:

```
datetimes = pd.PeriodIndex(reformatted_quarters.values, freq='Q').to_timestamp()
```

Comment: The first step works, but I receive an error for the second step: datetimes = pd.PeriodIndex(reformatted_quarters, freq='Q').to_timestamp()
print(datetimes)

Comment: @KashThak Thanks for the heads up. There was a recent change in the `PeriodIndex` expected data type, so depending on your Pandas version, try using `pd.PeriodIndex(reformatted_quarters.values ...` instead. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(quarter) => new Date(quarter.slice(-4), 3 * (quarter.slice(1, 2) - 1), 1)
```

This will give you the start of every quarter (e.g. `q42019` will give `2019-10-01`).

You should probably include some validation since it will just keep rolling over months (e.g. q52019 = q12020 = 2020-01-01)